# Multiple identical GPG Keys. What can cause that?

Tags: yum, rpm, chef, keys

I'm using OpsCode Chef to manage all my VMs, but since the last week, I'm having issues with one VM.

When running chef, it hangs right at the beginning. After a bit of investigation, I found out that if I run rpm -qa, it shows me A LOT of gpg-pubkey-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx in which many of them are duplicates of others.

It think this is what causes chef to hang and yum to be unable to install any packet.

Now, can you guys confirm that this is a problem? Also, do any of you know a way to find out what gpg-key is related to what program?

I tried to delete one of the key, but this also seem to hang and I have to kill it with the -9 option.

I'm a bit confused with what's going on with this VM!

Thanks for any help.

Found out that some package are set to be installed with --nogpgcheck.

Maybe this is what is causing the problem??

Comment: http://xkcd.com/221/

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question, the multiple identical GPG key entries can be the result of someone or some process running `rpm --import` multiple times on the same key files.